# Is it true that $\chi _{\pi |_H}(yxy^{-1})= \chi_\pi (x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. We have representation $\pi$ of $G$. We consider representation $\pi |_H$ of $H$. Let $y, x \in G$ such that $yxy^{-1}\in H$. Then is it true that $\chi _{\pi |_H}(yxy^{-1})= \chi_\pi (x)$ ?
I think yes as $\pi|_H(yxy^{-1} )=\pi(yxy^{-1})=\pi(x)$. Thus $\chi _{\pi |_H}(yxy^{-1})= \chi_\pi (x)$.

Comment: That seems to be correct.